# ExtJS 6 How to change the color of a sprite

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

How can I change the color of the drawing with a button I tried using the code below but it doesn't work, is there more efficient way of changing the color in sencha ext js like when a button is clicked a color grid will appear?

Used this example: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#free-paint

View

```
 tbar: ['->', {
        text: 'Color',
        handler: function (button) {
            var draw = Ext.getCmp('sprite');
            if (strokeStyle == yellow) {
                strokeStyle: new Ext.util.Color(255,255,0)
                button.setText('Yellow');
             } else {
                strokeStyle: new Ext.util.Color(0,30,255)
                button.setText('Blue');
             }
        }];
```

Component

```
 me.sprite = surface.add({
    type: 'path',
    path: ['M', me.list[0], me.list[1], 'L', me.list[0] + 1e-1, me.list[1] + 1e-1],
    lineWidth: 20,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineJoin: 'round',
    draggable: 'true',
    strokeStyle: new Ext.util.Color(0,0,0)
    });
    surface.renderFrame();
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with `Ext.draw.*` components but, according to the docs, to change color of a [Ext.draw.sprite.Sprite](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.draw.sprite.Sprite.html) you can use [`setAttributes()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.draw.sprite.Sprite.html#method-setAttributes) method like this:

```
sprite.setAttributes({
    strokeStyle: color
});
```

To pick color you can use [Ext.ux.colorpick.Field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.ux.colorpick.Field.html).

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bfl) to illustrate.